# rails Error: assets Precompiling assets failed. Cannot find package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, webpack-2, yarn-lock.json

I am getting this error while trying to push my ruby on rails app

```
   % git push heroku master 
    Enumerating objects: 1427, done.
    Counting objects: 100% (1427/1427), done.
    Delta compression using up to 8 threads
    Compressing objects: 100% (1405/1405), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (1413/1413), 30.60 MiB | 26.56 MiB/s, done.
    Total 1413 (delta 145), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
    remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (145/145), completed with 13 local objects.
    remote: Updated 6433 paths from 29fce6d
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
    remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
    remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
    remote:             Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
    remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
    remote: -----> Ruby app detected
    remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.3.25
    remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
    remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    remote: 
    remote: ###### WARNING:
    remote: 
    remote:        No ruby version specified in the Gemfile.lock
    remote:        
    remote:        We could not determine the version of Ruby from your Gemfile.lock.
    remote:        
    remote:          $ bundle platform --ruby
    remote:          No ruby version specified
    remote:        
    remote:          $ bundle -v
    remote:          Bundler version 2.3.25
    remote:        
    remote:        
    remote:        Ensure the above command outputs the version of Ruby you expect. If you have a ruby version specified in your Gemfile, you can update the Gemfile.lock by running the following command:
    remote:        
    remote:          $ bundle update --ruby
    remote:        
    remote:        Make sure you commit the results to git before attempting to deploy again:
    remote:        
    remote:          $ git add Gemfile.lock
    remote:          $ git commit -m "update ruby version"
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.6
    remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.3.25
    remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
    remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
    remote:        Using rake 13.1.0
    remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.2.3
    remote:        Using minitest 5.22.2
    remote:        Using zeitwerk 2.6.13
    remote:        Using erubi 1.12.0
    remote:        Using racc 1.7.3
    remote:        Using crass 1.0.6
    remote:        Fetching rack 2.2.8.1
    remote:        Using builder 3.2.4
    remote:        Using nio4r 2.7.0
    remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
    remote:        Using marcel 1.0.2
    remote:        Using mini_mime 1.1.5
    remote:        Using date 3.3.4
    remote:        Using timeout 0.4.1
    remote:        Using msgpack 1.7.2
    remote:        Using bundler 2.3.25
    remote:        Using ffi 1.16.3
    remote:        Using json 2.7.1
    remote:        Using method_source 1.0.0
    remote:        Using pg 1.5.5
    remote:        Fetching thor 1.3.1
    remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
    remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
    remote:        Using tilt 2.3.0
    remote:        Using semantic_range 3.0.0
    remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
    remote:        Using i18n 1.14.1
    remote:        Using tzinfo 2.0.6
    remote:        Using nokogiri 1.13.10 (x86_64-linux)
    remote:        Fetching activesupport 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Using loofah 2.22.0
    remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.6
    remote:        Using net-protocol 0.2.2
    remote:        Using bootsnap 1.18.3
    remote:        Using puma 5.6.8
    remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
    remote:        Using recaptcha 5.9.0
    remote:        Using sassc 2.4.0
    remote:        Using turbolinks 5.2.1
    remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.5.0
    remote:        Using net-imap 0.3.7
    remote:        Using net-pop 0.1.2
    remote:        Using net-smtp 0.4.0.1
    remote:        Using mail 2.8.1
    remote:        Installing rack 2.2.8.1
    remote:        Installing thor 1.3.1
    remote:        Installing activesupport 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Using rack-proxy 0.7.7
    remote:        Using sprockets 4.2.1
    remote:        Using rack-test 2.1.0
    remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.2.0
    remote:        Using globalid 1.2.1
    remote:        Fetching activemodel 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Fetching actionview 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Fetching activejob 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing activejob 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing activemodel 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing actionview 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Fetching activerecord 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Using jbuilder 2.11.5
    remote:        Fetching actionpack 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing actionpack 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing activerecord 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Fetching actioncable 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Fetching actionmailer 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Fetching railties 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing actionmailer 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing actioncable 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing railties 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.4.2
    remote:        Using mail_form 1.10.1
    remote:        Fetching activestorage 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing activestorage 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Fetching actionmailbox 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Fetching actiontext 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing actiontext 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Installing actionmailbox 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
    remote:        Using webpacker 5.4.4
    remote:        Fetching rails 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Using sass-rails 6.0.0
    remote:        Installing rails 6.1.7.7
    remote:        Bundle complete! 18 Gemfile dependencies, 68 gems now installed.
    remote:        Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
    remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
    remote:        Bundle completed (3.07s)
    remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
    remote:        Removing activestorage (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing actioncable (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing actionview (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing rack (2.2.8)
    remote:        Removing activemodel (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing actionmailer (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing thor (1.3.0)
    remote:        Removing activerecord (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing actionpack (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing railties (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing activejob (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing actionmailbox (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing rails (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing actiontext (6.1.7.6)
    remote:        Removing activesupport (6.1.7.6)
    remote: 
    remote: ###### WARNING:
    remote: 
    remote:        Installing a default version (20.9.0) of Node.js.
    remote:        This version is not pinned and can change over time, causing unexpected failures.
    remote:        
    remote:        Heroku recommends placing the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack in front of
    remote:        `heroku/ruby` to install a specific version of node:
    remote:        
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#node-js-support
    remote: 
    remote: 
    remote: ###### WARNING:
    remote: 
    remote:        Installing a default version (1.22.19) of Yarn
    remote:        This version is not pinned and can change over time, causing unexpected failures.
    remote:        
    remote:        Heroku recommends placing the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack in front of the `heroku/ruby`
    remote:        buildpack as it offers more comprehensive Node.js support, including the ability to
    remote:        customise the Node.js version:
    remote:        
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#node-js-support
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Installing node-v20.9.0-linux-x64
    remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.19
    remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
    remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
    remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
    remote:        /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:66: warning: already initialized constant Net::ProtocRetryError
    remote:        /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:68: warning: previous definition of ProtocRetryError was here
    remote:        /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:206: warning: already initialized constant Net::BufferedIO::BUFSIZE
    remote:        /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:214: warning: previous definition of BUFSIZE was here
    remote:        /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:503: warning: already initialized constant Net::NetPrivate::Socket
    remote:        /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:541: warning: previous definition of Socket was here
    remote:        ➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
    remote:        ➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 224ms
    remote:        ➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
    remote:        ➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 288ms
    remote:        ➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
    remote:        ➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:3.36.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
    remote:        ➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 5s 379ms
    remote:        ➤ YN0000: Done in 6s 149ms
    remote:        Compiling...
    remote:        Compilation failed:
    remote:        Hash: 24283f8d3862ee7a8706
    remote:        Version: webpack 4.47.0
    remote:        Time: 592ms
    remote:        Built at: 02/29/2024 7:55:45 PM
    remote:         2 assets
    remote:        Entrypoint application = js/application-3c25984e64a984f5fa6e.js js/application-3c25984e64a984f5fa6e.js.map
    remote:        [0] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 4.43 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
    remote:        
    remote:        ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
    remote:        Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    remote:        Error: Cannot find package '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods' imported from /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/babel-virtual-resolve-base.js
    remote:            at new NodeError (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:194:5)
    remote:            at packageResolve (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:908:9)
    remote:            at moduleResolve (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:937:20)
    remote:            at defaultResolve (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:1007:15)
    remote:            at resolve (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:1020:12)
    remote:            at tryImportMetaResolve (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:142:45)
    remote:            at resolveStandardizedNameForImport (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:164:19)
    remote:            at resolveStandardizedName (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:173:22)
    remote:            at loadPlugin (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:52:20)
    remote:            at loadPlugin.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at createDescriptor (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:140:16)
    remote:            at createDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at step (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/gensync/index.js:261:32)
    remote:            at evaluateAsync (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/gensync/index.js:291:5)
    remote:            at /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/gensync/index.js:44:11
    remote:            at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at Function.async (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/gensync/index.js:43:15)
    remote:            at Function.all (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216:13)
    remote:            at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at createDescriptors (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:102:41)
    remote:            at createDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at createPluginDescriptors (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:99:17)
    remote:            at createPluginDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/functional.js:39:27
    remote:            at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at mergeChainOpts (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:349:34)
    remote:            at mergeChainOpts.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at chainWalker (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:316:14)
    remote:            at chainWalker.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at loadFileChain (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:191:24)
    remote:            at loadFileChain.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at buildRootChain (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:77:27)
    remote:            at buildRootChain.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:72:62)
    remote:            at loadPrivatePartialConfig.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at loadPartialConfig (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:115:25)
    remote:            at loadPartialConfig.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at step (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/gensync/index.js:269:25)
    remote:            at evaluateAsync (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/gensync/index.js:291:5)
    remote:            at /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/gensync/index.js:93:9
    remote:            at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at async (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/gensync/index.js:92:14)
    remote:            at stopHiding - secret - don't use this - v1 (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.js:47:12)
    remote:            at loadPartialConfigAsync (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/index.js:34:85)
    remote:            at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:126:26)
    remote:            at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at asyncGeneratorStep (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:3:103)
    remote:            at _next (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:4:194)
    remote:            at /tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:4:364
    remote:            at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    remote:            at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:4:97)
    remote:            at Object._loader (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:210:18)
    remote:            at Object.loader (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:48:18)
    remote:            at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_4f88f8e6/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:44:12)
    remote:        
    remote: 
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote: 
    remote: !   Push rejected to vancouver-786-limo-services.
    remote: 
    To https://git.heroku.com/vancouver-786-limo-services.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "vancouver-786-limo-services",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.4.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.4",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.5.0",
    "yarn": "3.4.1"
  }
}
```

my ruby version is
ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin20]

Comment: Known issue with Rails 6 - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/48372 -- possible workarounds described